# Delegates act as value types

Tags: c#, delegates

I have just discovered one strange thing:

```
Action a1 = () => Console.Write("1 ");
Action a2 = () => Console.Write("2 ");
Action tmp = a1;
a1 += a2;
a2 = tmp;
Console.Write("a1:\t");
a1();   //a1:  1 2
Console.Write("\na2:\t");
a2();   //a2:  1
Console.ReadLine();
```

I expected both statements to return "1 2";
Why it isn't so?

Comment: Delegates are reference types. They are also immutable, like String.

Comment: @mike thanks for the quick answer!
i find it quite counter-intuitive.. so if i want to reference a delegate (a changeable collection of actions to call from different objects) i should wrap it into a class?

Comment: Yes you would have to wrap it in something if want other classes to see the changes. Again, similar to string. If you want several collaborating classes to get the same value they need a reference to the same (mutable) object.

Comment: @mike, thanks. do you know what it was the reason to make delegates immutable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why they are immutable.

Comment: @mikez because there is no need for them to be mutable, and being immutable solves a wide range of problems ;p The comparison to string concatenation is a very good one, IMO

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm aware of the tradeoffs of mutable/immutable collections. What I can't comment on are the use cases and underlying design concerns involved with the implementation of delegates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, delegates are reference types. They are also immutable, like System.String. This surprises a lot of people. Imagine you had the same code with strings. This is, I think, clearer:

```
String s1 = "1 ";
String s2 = "2 ";
String stmp = s1;
s1 += s2;
s2 = stmp;
Console.WriteLine(s1);  //  1 2
Console.WriteLine(s2);  //  1
```

Calling `+=` does not mutate an underlying instance of a delegate, it produces a new delegate with the right-hand side appended to the new delegate's invocation list. `+=` is really just sugar for `Delegate.Combine`, the compiler produces code similar to the following:

```
a1 = (Action)Delegate.Combine(a1, a2);
```

Which I think makes it a little more obvious that we are creating a new instance of a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you assigned the temp variable to a1 before you added on the additional event, which modified what the event was to do. if you wanted the same result of "1 2 ", you should have done:

```
a1 += a2;
a2 = a1;
```

This would result in the same result that you were expecting. The other approach would be if you did something like this:

```
a1 += a2;
Action temp = a1;
a2 = temp;
```

This would also result in the result that you were expecting.